# How to find the nearest location (geo maps) with high performance in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a delivery app that has drivers, and I want to find a way with high performance to find the nearest driver in a certain location using in spring boot.

I am using MySQL DB with jpaRepository in spring boot as a back-end. And planning to put most of the business logic in the server, and make the mobile apps provide only a simple information such as finding the source and destination locations.

The question is, what is the best way to place the current location for the drivers? and what is the best way to find the nearest driver in a certain location?

What are the current technologies to perform this with spring boot?

Comment: Use a DB that allows to index data geographically, like (but not restricted to) Elastisearch or MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

the two questions are on the same meaning which is searching for the shortest path 
you can use A* to search for the nearest driver then place the start node to the driver and report to the user the path 
with Geolocation or Geocoding Google APIs 
you can use longitude and latitude to build a graph then search across this graph
or you can use another google maps API called Distance Matrix Service that can help you 
Follow the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix